# What is Php Ajax Response : - > See My code if(response == 1) what is meaning of if(response == 1)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'addremove.php',
           type: 'post',
            data: {path: imgElement_src,request: 2},
              success: function(response){


           if(response == 1){
             $('#content_'+num).remove();
           }


          }
        });
```

Comment: it means "if response is equal to one"

Comment: I think it is better to use success and fail. In both case response is returned so beware of the code you use. Also the meaning is if response returned by ajax call has the value=1

Comment: what is   == 1 is here